# Get first three characters from DayOfWeek , Month

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, dayofweek

I've a datetime:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2003, 5, 1);
dt.DayOfWeek // returns Thursday
```

How I can split only first three characters from `DayOfWeek` e.g. `Thu`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-ddd-custom-format-specifier

Comment: `var shortDayName = dt.DayOfWeek.Substring(0,3)`

Comment: or `dt.ToString("ddd");` if you need I18N and realise that not everyone abbreviates day names to exactly 3 letters long.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you mean for it to work in different cultures, then your best bet is probably:

```
var abbr = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedDayName(dayOfWeek);
```

where `culture` is a `CultureInfo`, for example:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```

In English cultures, this is the 3-letter version:

```
Sun
Mon
Tue
Wed
Thu
Fri
Sat
```

Comment: what if I do same for month?

Comment: @Asif.Ali then: `GetAbbreviatedMonthName`

Comment: where should I place if datetime format is `12/21/2017`?

Comment: @Asif.Ali what do you mean "where should I place"? you asked specifically for the 3-letter (abbreviated) version of things - the "datetime format" is irrelevant: once parsed, a `DateTime` *does not have* a format; it *does*, however, have a `.Month` and `.DayOfWeek`

Answer (score 1):

Marcs approach is the best here. But if i understand your question in a more general way, how to get the first three letters of an `enum`-value, you can use string methods if you use [`enum.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2003, 5, 1);
string dow = dt.DayOfWeek.ToString();
dow = dow.Length > 3 ? dow.Remove(3) : dow;
```